# minicom not recognizing the USB modem

Tags: usb-modem, modem

when inserting the USB GSM modem Huawei K3565, the network manager recognize it and i'm able to activate it from the network manage, but when runin the minicom it says:

```
minicom: cannot open /dev/modem: no such file or directory
```

but when executing the command:

```
# wvdialconf /etc/wvdial.conf
```

the result

```
#found modem on /dev/ttyUSB0
```

what i'm missing or what is the problem

Answer (score 10):

Your problem is:

- `minicom: cannot open /dev/modem`
- `found modem on /dev/ttyUSB0`

`/dev/modem` is not the same as `/dev/ttyUSB0`. Your modem is device `/dev/ttyUSB0`. Minicom is failing because it is trying to open `/dev/modem/`. Change the device in the minicom settings or run:

```
minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB0
```

A more creative solution would be to add a udev rule that creates the /dev/modem symlink automatically. Create /etc/udev/rules.d/95-usb-modem.rules

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="12d0", ATTRS{idProduct}=="1001", SYMLINK+="modem"
```

Replace the 12d0 and 1001 with the vendor:product for your modem from `lsusb`

Comment: the 1st issue is the K3565 is connected to (2 tty_usbs) ttyUSB0 & ttyUSB1, i noticed when unplug the modem from the USB port both the ttyUSB0 & ttyUSB1 disappeared, so how to fine this modem is connected to which one exactly.. BTW k3565 has internal CD-Rom which include the installation files for windows drivers.

2nd, how to link this USB to the modem using generic Linux or (ubuntu/Debian) command, without editing any files

Comment: BTW, there is no folder /dev/modem/    ????why

Comment: Do you have a file `/dev/gsmmodem0` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you get:

```
minicom: cannot open /dev/modem: No such file or directory
```

Link /dev/modem to your serial port device. For COM1, this is usually /dev/ttyS0:

```
ln -s /dev/ttyS0 /dev/modem
```

That could solve it.

Comment: Not good. `minicom-s` will provide you with an "interface" to setup you serial connection.